# COMException when trying to use a Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, comexception

I have an ASP.net WebService which uses a Library, this has a dependency on some third party .dlls.

If I add a reference to the Library to my webservice, I get a COMException and I can't load the site. I thought it may be to do with aspnet user credentials, so I have tried impersonating and using processModel in machine.config but nothing seems to work.

The .dlls are for communicating with hardware so I am not even using them on the server just other parts of the library, is there any way I can fix this?

I'm running on Windows XP Pro SP3 with Visual 2008 SP1 and .net 3.5.

I am thinking the only way of fixing it, is to split up the library into hardware and non-hardware based.

Cheers, Sarkie

```
    The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F) 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[COMException (0x8007007f): The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)]

[FileLoadException: A procedure imported by 'OBIDISC4NETnative, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=900ed37a7058e4f2' could not be loaded.]
   System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) +0
   System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) +43
   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +127
   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +142
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +46

[ConfigurationErrorsException: A procedure imported by 'OBIDISC4NETnative, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=900ed37a7058e4f2' could not be loaded.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +613
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +203
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +105
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +178
   System.Web.Compilation.WebDirectoryBatchCompiler..ctor(VirtualDirectory vdir) +163
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectoryInternal(VirtualDirectory vdir, Boolean ignoreErrors) +53
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectory(VirtualDirectory vdir, VirtualPath virtualDir, Boolean ignoreErrors) +175
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) +83
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) +261
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) +101
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) +83
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath) +10
   System.Web.UI.WebServiceParser.GetCompiledType(String inputFile, HttpContext context) +43
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String verb, String url, String filePath) +180
   System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated) +102
   System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig) +193
   System.Web.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +93
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3082; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3082
```

Comment: Do you have DllImports for OBIDISC4NETnative.dll?

Comment: I just reference it.

I have reflected both the .dlls and they have some DLLImports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to  Kim Gräsman for setting me on the right track.

The reason the procedure was missing, is because asp.net is loading the .dlls from %windir%\system32 not current directory.

Looking in there, were some very old version of the .dlls (not sure who/how they got there). Deleting these showing a FileIOException, so replacing these with the latest .dlls seems to have fixed it.

Comment: sarkie, glad it helped! I see now that the error message hints that the referenced dll has failed to import.